# C++ Is there any guarantee that literals conditions generated by a template will be optimized away?

Tags: c++

Excuse any mistakes in my code, I'm still learning C++ syntax. My question is not about whether the code is correct but whether a literal expression will be optimized away.

Let's say I have a function generated from a non-type template like this:

```
template <bool add>
int addIt(int a, int b) {
   if (add) {
       return a + b;
   } else {
       return a - b;
   }
}

int v = addIt<true>(10, 5);
```

From my understanding, the compiler should expand the template to:

```
int addIt_someID(int a, int b) {
   if (true) {
       return a + b;
   } else {
       return a - b;
   }
}

int v = addIt_someID(10, 5);
```

But since it now says `if (true)` it should be able to remove that entire branch, resulting in this:

```
void addIt_someID(int a, int b) {
       return a + b;
}

int v = addIt_someID(10, 5);
```

This should be standard compiler behavior... but is this behavior well enough established that I can be certain of it from all major compilers?

I'm relying upon this behavior for a transpiler, and if it's not guaranteed I will have to implement it myself... if it is guaranteed I can let the C++ compiler to do it and that will save me a *lot* of time in having to parse and evaluate this myself.

Comment: No **optimizations** are guaranteed by standard, you have to "see" with your compiler. I'm confident that popular compiler with appropriate optimization flag generate code without branching in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is never guaranteed for regular `if` (although I would say chaneces are pretty high). There are two ways to be sure. Simpler one requires C++17 (btw `addIt` seems to return wrong type):

```
template <bool add>
int addIt(int a, int b) {
   if constexpr (add) {
       return a + b;
   } else {
       return a - b;
   }
}

int v = addIt<true>(10, 5);
```

`if constexpr` guerantees that this will be evaluated in compile time.

Another option is using template metaprogramming/explicit template specialization. For your code this would be pretty simple:

```
template <bool add>
int addIt(int a, int b);

template<> int addIt<true>(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
template<> int addIt<false>(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

int v = addIt<true>(10, 5);
```

For other cases you would need some more work like using `std::enable_if` and stuff like this